# BBM connected app interoperability between BB10 and BB Java

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, bb-messenger

Will a java based (OS5) BBM connected app be able to list the contacts who use the bb10 version of the app, if both apps use the same UUID ?

I would like to release a bb10 app with the same uuid as used in bb7 app, if the bb10 app can download the list of contacts who use the bb7 app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as they are both releases in the same product in BlackBerry World.

Comment: How can this be tested in pre production environment?